# Matrix with subscripts in matplotlib python

Tags: python, linux, matrix, matplotlib

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Matrix.svg

Is there a way to plot that image in python using matplotlib?
I atleast would like it to have the variable with subscripts in the plot.

I could not see that in matplotlib gallery unfortunately.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html and using `plt.text` as done here http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/dannys_example.html?

Comment: Let me give that a shot!